# Android Emulator does not run any sample app. Is VirtualBox an issue? "Host" OS Windows XP-64, "Virtual" XP Pro 32 bit

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-emulator, virtualbox

I have a quad-core 64 bit Windows XP system with 8GB of RAM.

I installed VirtualBox specifically to host Windows XP 32 bit.

I installed the very latest Android SDK and its prerequisites via the installer EXE.

I installed Eclipse (Helios Service Release 1) from the site's ZIP to c:\eclipse on the virtual machine's hard disk (did not run any setup whatsoever) and installed the ADT plugin as per the instructions. The plugin was configured with the Android SDK path as required.

I created a "Android Virtual Device" containing 512mb SD and supporting API 11.

I then run Eclipse and made a new project from existing source. I picked the "snake" sample source from the samples (android-11 directory) and then after it "assimilated" itself (lol) I selected "run as" then "Android Application"

The emulator starts up fine, and the message "installing snake.apk" is displayed.

Then "Done!"

However, the emulator does not run the game. The emulator goes into screensaver mode, and I can press keys to rotate the screen etc, use trackball etc.

I've waited for minutes for the game to start, I did read that the emulator takes time to start up the game, but absolutely no joy. I can't wait hours to debug my application, what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Does anything show up in the Logcat pane in Eclipse? There could be an exception very early on.

Comment: Have you tried running the game by starting from within the emulator? What kind of game is this? 3D? Maybe thats a problem...

Comment: @WarrenFaith: I can't see how to get to the "installed apps" part in the emulator. I should have mentioned that the emulator is one large black rectangle on the screen with "A N D R O I D _" at start up, *then* it goes into screen-saver mode. I press "Home" and "Menu" (Home key on my keyboard and Page Up) and nothing happens. Sometimes I see "Google" and a hexagonal background but navigating it is impossible. Bear in mind I've installed the emulator "as-is" and made no changes to anything, no xml, just run from Eclipse.

Comment: You need to unlock the screen. There must be a possibility to drag&drop a button on the screen to release the screensaver. Then you should see your application running (when I see the lockscreen correctly you need to interact with the "lock" symbol....)

Comment: could you provide a screenshot with the latest screen you see? just to be sure that your emulator has booted till the very end.

Comment: At the moment all I see is a strobing "Android" sign in high-res.

Comment: "Starting activity com.example.android.skeletonapp.SkeletonActivity on device emulator-5554" - and then the screen is blank. So now I'm going to try to Telnet to unlock it, because pressing Menu and Home emulator keys does absolutely nothing.

Comment: "Failed to install SkeletonActivity.apk on device 'emulator-5554!" - now this is a Android sample app, correct API version. I used ADB to send INPUT KEYEVENT 82 and the emulator unlocked, but then my app terminated, why oh why is this so difficult??

Comment: I found that the SkeletonActivity app has been installed on Android, but it will not run from Eclipse. Instead I have to navigate to the app in the emulator, and run it manually. I'm not impressed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Pressing Page Up solved it for me, but it did show some sort of warning message before displaying the application.